# Print XML content of SOAP message

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am using Apache CXF for my webservices. I've created an instance of `AbstractSoapInterceptor`. In its `public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault` method I would like to print the XML content of the intercepted message to the console. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@cxf.apache.org/msg13206.html) out and search for INBOUND INTERCEPTOR. Will place it here for reference...

```
public class InterceptorMensajeSOAPIn extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

      private static Logger log =
Logger.getLogger(InterceptorMensajeSOAPIn.class);



      private SAAJInInterceptor saajIn = new SAAJInInterceptor();

      public InterceptorMensajeSOAPIn(){

            super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL);

            getAfter().add(SAAJInInterceptor.class.getName());

      } 


      public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {

        SOAPMessage soapMessage = getSOAPMessage(message);

        try {

                  soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                  e.printStackTrace();

            }
      }


      private SOAPMessage getSOAPMessage(SoapMessage smsg){

            SOAPMessage soapMessage = smsg.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);

        if (soapMessage == null) {

            saajIn.handleMessage(smsg);

            soapMessage = smsg.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);

        }   

        return soapMessage;

      }
}
```

Comment: Would this solution work with cxf 3.x?  I tried it and the call to getContent always returns null, but maybe I'm doing something else wrong or the api has changed in 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

Any reason you cannot just use the `LoggingInInterceptor` that is shipped with CXF?   You could just grab the code for that and use that as a basis, but in 2.3, the `LoggingInInterceptor` was enhanced to allow specifying a printstream and such to use, so it might "just work".

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a feature for this: `org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature`:

```
<jaxws:endpoint ...>
    <jaxws:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature"/>
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```